# How do you resize a google ad and keep it inside a DIV and make it not bigger than the DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I have the Display ad as my google ad unit (which is responsive). I want the ad generated by google to be contained inside a 350x250 DIV container. However, currently, when google generates an ad its 160x600, even though my `my-ad` says the div box should be 350x250. How can I fix this?

```css
.my-ad {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 0px;
    min-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-ad">
  <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
       style="display:block"
       data-ad-client="ca-pub-CENSORED"
       data-ad-slot="CENSORED"
       data-ad-format="auto"
       data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
  <script>
       (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your slot to be no bigger than 300x250 then I feel like you shouldn't use responsive. For example on mobile responsive ads are taking full width which is often bigger than 300px.

Have you considered just having fixed-size ads? For example like this: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183363?hl=en

Comment: The issue with fixed ads is that it only displays the fixed size. They don't even display anything smaller